# Converting multiple if-else logic to for loop

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop, unity-game-engine

Currently I have multiple if-else loops in my code, such as:

```js
if (a > 2 && a < 4)
{
  // do something
}
else if (a > 4 && a < 6)
{
  // do something
}
else if (a > 6 && a < 8)
{
  // do something
}

... and so on.
```

is there a way to re-arrange this into a simpler FOR loop? or any other loop which can make the code more optimized?

Comment: I fail to see a for .. loop here, perhaps you mean `switch`?

Comment: switch does not shorten the code. Is there any other way you'd suggest I make the code short and more optimized instead of having multiple (in my case 30) if-else statements?

Comment: a > 2 && a < 4 is the same as a == 3?? Same goes with the rest of ifs?

Comment: @KalelWade That's not true if 'a' is a double or other such number other than an integer.

Comment: I hurriedly made the difference 1, you can assume it be more than 1, such as a > 2 && a < 6, and so on.

Comment: @CalebB good call - made the assumption that it was an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 2; ; i += 2)
    {
        if (a > i && a < i + 2)
        {
            //Do your thing
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: but then //do your thing is a different statement in each if-else condition that I'm using. Here, that would be exactly the same, irrespective of what the value of i (or a) actually is. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @Daqs you didn't include your thing, if you show it we might be able to spot a pattern!

Comment: @Daqs In addition this sounds like a solution you might want to use some polymorphism with depending on the actions taking place.

Comment: the only pattern that there is to it, is the difference which you've already spotted. I guess, that's as much as you can do. I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `switch` if you wanted to check for exact values. However, since your conditions are based on mathematic expressions, you are likely better off sticking with what you've got. It may look cluttered, but it's likely already the most efficient way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: are you sure? I'm new at programming but this seems so unoptimized and inefficient? I see my code and all I see is 30 if-else loops. You sure there isn't another work-around because I can't use switch (as you said I'm not doing exact values).

Comment: Without knowing more about what you're doing, it's difficult to suggest how to optimize it.  If there are patterns in your conditions which can be simplified, that will help.  Or you may be able to eliminate condition checks altogether.  We need more info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is literally all that I'm doing. There is nothing more to it. I'm comparing an integer variable's value in batches like in my example above, where each batch of comparison yields a different output. Do you think in this there could be a pattern? The difference between values being compared is the same. Can something be done about that? e.g. (a>2) && (a<6) -> here difference is 4, which is how much it is in each comparison.

Comment: Still need more info.  What happens in `// do something`?

Comment: You're right. I should've mentioned that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, all you need is put the values in an array as shown below and call the methods dynamically, is that what you are looking for?

```
var range = [3,5,7] //defined the range as >2 and <4 is equal to 3 and so on.

$.each(range, function(i, val){

  window[PerformActionByVal + val]();//call the specific function

});

function PerformActionByVal3()
{
}

function PerformActionByVal5()
{
}
```

Comment: I highly doubt he want's a jQuery solution

Comment: @Jonesy I also doubt this, however the op does mention this running on unity which runs both C# and js so the solution could be a jquery one. Just saying.